# Self hosted Git server to be run on linux

Tags: linux, self-hosted, git

I would like to run on my server a git server in order to use the software `pass` (aka `password-store` on android and `pass` on iOS). That's all I need the git server for, so it should be as lightweight and safe as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to self-host a git server, then I would recommend you to purchase Atlassian Bitbucket server for small cost ($ 10 per Year).

Go to "https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/pricing?tab=self-hosted" and click "Looking for Server pricing". Choose your Bitbucket user tier for 10 users.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any freeware sw you would recommend?

Comment: Check this website: https://www.linux.com/LEARN/HOW-RUN-YOUR-OWN-GIT-SERVER

Answer (score 0):

I would simply setup an SSH server. On a Debian install, you would:

```
apt-get install openssh-server git
```

Then setup a bare git repository in your home:

```
umask 077
git init --bare pass.git
```

Then you can add this as a remote to your pass repository with a simple:

```
pass git remote add origin yourserver.example.com:pass.git
pass git push -u origin master
```

Now of course, I assume you know how to put that server online on a public IP, which I consider out of scope for this question.